# Only one CPU core handling network interrupts

Tags: streaming, raspberry-pi3, docker-swarm, ethernet, interrupt-handling

I developed a video streaming server in golang which receives multiple streams via a regular TCP connection and broadcasts them over HTTP.

This is working on my raspberryPi cluster which I am running in docker swarm. The server is horizontally distributed among all raspberries. All instances receive all streams, the load distribution comes when distributing among many clients over HTTP.

A single stream is pretty heavy, about 16Mbit/s of bandwidth used.

It works pretty well as I get 32fps almost without delay.

I decided to check how much CPU and memory my programs are consuming via htop. When I run it as the root user I see my server using around 50% CPU, which I thought was ok since it was receiving 4 simultaneous streams at 32fps. But then I ran htop with the pi user and noticed another process `ksoftirqd` consuming another 50% CPU (don't know why I can't see process when running htop as root).

I did some research and learned this is a special little process that handles delayed system interrupts (or something similar). This kind of makes sense since I'm receiving heavy load via the eth0 interface.

I then looked into `/proc/interrupts`:

```
       CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
 16:          0          0          0          0  bcm2836-timer   0 Edge      arch_timer
 17:   92241367  299499641  352012196  317363321  bcm2836-timer   1 Edge      arch_timer
 23:     288978          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level   1 Edge      3f00b880.mailbox
 24:   25146874          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level   2 Edge      VCHIQ doorbell
 46:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  48 Edge      bcm2708_fb dma
 48:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  50 Edge      DMA IRQ
 50:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  52 Edge      DMA IRQ
 51:     530982          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  53 Edge      DMA IRQ
 54:      13573          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  56 Edge      DMA IRQ
 55:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  57 Edge      DMA IRQ
 56:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  58 Edge      DMA IRQ
 59:       3354          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  61 Edge      bcm2835-auxirq
 62: 3696376760          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  64 Edge      dwc_otg, dwc_otg_pcd, dwc_otg_hcd:usb1
 79:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  81 Edge      3f200000.gpio:bank0
 80:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  82 Edge      3f200000.gpio:bank1
 83:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  85 Edge      3f804000.i2c
 84:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  86 Edge      3f204000.spi
 86:     460008          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  88 Edge      mmc0
 87:       5270          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  89 Edge      uart-pl011
 92:    4975621          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  94 Edge      mmc1
220:       3352          0          0          0  bcm2835-auxirq   0 Edge      serial
FIQ:              usb_fiq
IPI0:          0          0          0          0  CPU wakeup interrupts
IPI1:          0          0          0          0  Timer broadcast interrupts
IPI2:   41355699  278691553  311249136  291769396  Rescheduling interrupts
IPI3:       7758       9176       8710       9334  Function call interrupts
IPI4:          0          0          0          0  CPU stop interrupts
IPI5:    1387927    1201820    2860486    1356720  IRQ work interrupts
IPI6:          0          0          0          0  completion interrupts
Err:          0
```

As you can see interrupt 62 is the one that is called the most by far and only being handled by CPU0. I suspect that this interrupt is the eth0 interrupt (how can I confirm this?). So I thought I could configure this so the interrupt would be handled by all CPUs.

So I looked into `/proc/irq/62/smp_affinity_list` and it's contents are `0-3` which seems correct and the `/proc/irq/62/smp_affinity` file contents are `f` which also seems correct.

So I don't understand why interrupt 62 is only being handled by CPU0.

Also don't understand why I can only see the `ksoftirqd` in the htop if I run it as pi instead of root (the owner of the process is root).

How can I configure the raspberry to handle that interrupt on all CPUs?

*** EDIT ***

I was checking for this on only one of the raspberries belonging to the cluster. Checking for this on the other hosts I saw similar results (just a little lower CPU usage). Strangely on another raspberry there is no `ksoftirqd` process consuming that much CPU.

Comment: Hi Esser420!! I am seeing the exactly same behavior with another video streaming service. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: The project has evolved and I now use h264 as the video format instead of MJPEG and the problem did not persist after that. It could be because of the much lower bandwidth usage. However I do still think there is something wrong in how the raspberrypi handles those interrupts

Comment: I found my way here because we have seen this on a swarm running centos 7 in a hyper-v environment. We dockerized one of our older services. When we tried to bring up 42 containers ie 21 services with 2 replicas the swarm struggled and had major issues. It even struggled to maintain leaders. We tracked this down to ksoftirqd but have not gone further yet.

Comment: Hoping that voting this up will lead someone to find a deeper problem. So you say this also happened on non raspberry hardware but with docker swarm. Maybe the issue lies there. I just avoided running kubernetes because it would be another process running on raspberry where memory is limited. Maybe on better hardware it is a good idea to switch to kubernetes.